# Forecast Time Series for weekly data

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to use script available in R blogger in below web page on my own data set.

https://www.r-bloggers.com/forecasting-weekly-data/

I have converted my data to time series and then modified script , but got error "Error in ...fourier(x, K, length(x) + (1:h)) : 
  K must be not be greater than period/2"
I sharing script which I have created, can anyone help me what kind of error is this.

```
DataFVM <- read.csv("AM1.csv", header=TRUE,na.strings=c("NULL",""))

Data <- subset(DataFVM,select=c(ID,Backlog))
Data <- Data[(Data$ID %in% c('905')),]
backlog <- as.vector(Data$Backlog)
backlog <- as.ts(backlog)

bestfit <- list(aicc=Inf)
for(i in 1:25)
{
  fit <- auto.arima(backlog, xreg=fourier(backlog, K=i), seasonal=FALSE)
  if(fit$aicc < bestfit$aicc)
    bestfit <- fit
  else break;
}
fc <- forecast(bestfit, xreg=fourierf(backlog, K=1, h=104))
```

Below is data-set which I am using

```
ID  Backlog
905 0.99
905 0.96
905 0.98
905 0.87
905 0.95
905 0.91
905 0.96
905 0.92
905 0.9
905 0.91
905 0.96
905 0.95
905 0.87
905 0.99
905 0.95
905 0.99
905 0.93
905 0.94
905 0.96
905 0.98
905 0.71
905 0.84
905 0.86
905 0.92
905 0.91
905 1
905 0.96
905 0.92
905 0.96
905 0.92
905 0.83
905 0.93
905 0.97
905 0.67
905 0.89
905 0.92
905 0.95
905 0.94
905 0.95
905 1
905 0.98
905 0.94
905 0.88
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason appears to be that the fourier function expects your time-series data to have a frequency associated with it.  So if you believe your data has a seasonality of 52, then change the following line like so:

```
#backlog <- as.ts(backlog)
backlog <- as.ts(backlog,frequency=52)
```

Now, fourier understands 52 to be the period.  So you can iterate 'i' anywhere from 1 to 25 where > 25 would produce the same error you're receiving now: K must be not be greater than period/2.

I took a quick crack at finding a model to represent the data.  Below is a plot of the partial autocorrelations showing a significant lag at 5, 13, and 20.

[image: Partial Autocorrelation]

After looking at a few SARIMAX models, I settled on the following equation which had the minimal MSE in the validation data set:

[0,0,0] [0,0,1]13

Seasonal MA: order 13,
X = dummy vector identifying the 2 significant drops,
and I included a constant

Below is the performance of a rolling 1 period ahead prediction:

[image: Validation Data Results]

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the details answer. Sorry I am bit new to this time series forecasting. I tried to find the way of identifying seasonality so that I can define frequency. But, I didn't found any material which will help me. Is there any document which can be used to identify seasonality. I have also tried with frequency=52, but while executing for loop for it was always throwing error not sure what should be counter for variable "i" needs to initialized

Comment: You can try using a Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) to detect whether you have any seasonalities in your data.  The following is a good read:
https://anomaly.io/detect-seasonality-using-fourier-transform-r/

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing information. This is really useful. I able to identify seasonality as 12 for my data, when I initialize frequency = 12 while executing for loop it throws error "Error in ...fourier(x, K, 1:length(x)) : 
  K must be not be greater than period/2", I tried all K values "fit <- auto.arima(backlog, xreg=fourier(backlog, K=2), seasonal=FALSE)" but didn't worked.